# Recursively serialize multiple Datatable hierarchies to JSON object

Tags: c#, json, recursion, datatable, table-per-hierarchy

I want to serialize multiple DataTables to JSON which are interrelated and it is possible there will be additional table are all set in the mapping table. In this case, I have 3 DataTables.

- Table A as parent
- Table B as the child of Table A
- Table C as the child of Table B

The JSON output should be

```
{
    "TableA": [
        {
            "ID": "2490",
            "TYPE": "Electronic",
            "TableB": [
                {
                    "ID": "2490",
                    "ITEM": "XMT123",
                    "RECEIPT_NUM": "59",
                    "TableC": [
                        {
                            "ID": "2490",
                            "ITEM": "XMT123",
                            "QUANTITY": "164"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "ID": "2491",
                    "ITEM": "XMT234",
                    "RECEIPT_NUM": "12",
                    "TableC": [
                        {
                            "ID": "2491",
                            "ITEM": "XMT234",
                            "QUANTITY": "92"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": "2491",
            "TYPE": "Electronic",
            "TableB": [
                {
                    "ID": "2491",
                    "ITEM": "XMT456",
                    "RECEIPT_NUM": "83",
                    "TableC": [
                        {
                            "ID": "2491",
                            "ITEM": "XMT456",
                            "QUANTITY": "261"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "ID": "2492",
                    "ITEM": "XMT567",
                    "RECEIPT_NUM": "77",
                    "TableC": [
                        {
                            "ID": "2492",
                            "ITEM": "XMT567",
                            "QUANTITY": "70"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've already tried code like this, but it doesn't seem to work

```
static void dataToJson(string connection_string, string query, string table_name)
{
    try
    {
        JArray jArray = new JArray();
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        DataTable inner_tbl = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
        conn.Open();
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn); // query to get parent
        adapter.Fill(tbl);
        foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
        {
            JObject jo = new JObject();
            foreach (DataColumn col in tbl.Columns)
            {
                jo.Add(new JProperty(col.ColumnName.ToString(), row[col].ToString()));
            }
            jArray.Add(jo);

            query = "i have query to get child";
            dataToJson(connection_string, query, table_child);                  
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        WriteLog(e.Message, GetCurrentMethod(e));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the parent or return the child in this recursive method. Also, you don't have to open `SqlConnection` every time if all the tables are in the same database.

Here is an example of passing the parent:

```
// Caller
JObject root = new JObject();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
{
    conn.Open();
    dataToJson(root, conn, query, "TableA");
}
Console.WriteLine(root.ToString());


static void dataToJson(JObject parent, SqlConnection conn, string query, string table_name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(table_name)) { return; }
    try
    {
        JArray jArray = new JArray();
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        //DataTable inner_tbl = new DataTable();
        //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
        //conn.Open();
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn); // query to get parent
        adapter.Fill(tbl);
        foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
        {
            JObject jo = new JObject();
            foreach (DataColumn col in tbl.Columns)
            {
                jo.Add(new JProperty(col.ColumnName.ToString(), row[col].ToString()));
            }
            query = "i have query to get child";
            // Set the child table name to "table_child"
            dataToJson(jo, conn, query, table_child);  // Pass the JObject as the parent

            jArray.Add(jo); 
            parent.Add(new JProperty(table_name, jArray));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        WriteLog(e.Message, GetCurrentMethod(e));
    }
}
```

By the way, I'm not sure how you get the child table's name so I used the following dictionary for testing.

```
static Dictionary<string, string> table_hierarchy = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// Initialize
table_hierarchy.Add("TableA", "TableB");
table_hierarchy.Add("TableB", "TableC");
table_hierarchy.Add("TableC", "");
```

Comment: It's work only 2 record on TableA. 3 next record it got error. Can not add property TableB to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Property with the same name already exists on object.

Comment: now it is working great, after catching with no exception. Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you for marking my answer as the best answer. Let me know if I need to update something on this.